# UIImageView is not showing correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

At this moment, my program looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the square with the rounded rectangles is an image but it doesn't show very well and am not sure how to solve this... Here is the class: http://pastebin.com/QPXbG1uK
The background window gets added here:

```
    UIImageView* background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"popupWindowBack.png"]] ;
background.center = CGPointMake(_bigPanelView.frame.size.width/2, _bigPanelView.frame.size.height/2);
[_bigPanelView addSubview: background];
```

Also what do I need to change if I want a simple view as the background instead of the image?

Comment: u need to set only correct Fram of superView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Your place I would stop using Center coordinates and specifically set it's frame rectangle:

```
background.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

background.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,_bigPanelView.frame.size.width-20, _bigPanelView.frame.size.height-20);
```

In this case - imageview will be 10 pix from top/left/right/bottom.

Remove this:

```
background.center = CGPointMake(_bigPanelView.frame.size.width/2, _bigPanelView.frame.size.height/2);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve your image fit your UIImageView try this:

```
background.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Also you need to set `background` frame to fit screen size, for example if you adding UIImageView in UIViewController class instance:

```
background.frame = self.view.frame;
```

Comment: Can you give me an example code since I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: I did like you said, but that is even more stuffed up: http://i50.tinypic.com/308hcmw.png

Comment: Can you give more information about what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've made a popup view, but now I'm using an image and actually I don't want to use that image as background, instead I want a lets say square/view that's a little smaller then the viewcontroller where I can put text on (or images)

Comment: @Shinonuma do you want to place your UIImageView on the top Layer?

Comment: It is a simple. take a view hierarchy ? What's the problem actually image is not properly setting or anything else ?.:)

Answer (score 1):

i think your image size is larger then bigPanelView view . plz set the background frame size of the bigPanelView. like

```
background.frame = bigPanelView.view.frame;
```